# How to show conditional custom fields using WordPress CMB2 plugin when a post is added new

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm a great fan of WordPress [CMB2 Plugin](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2) while calling custom meta boxes. I came to know that [it has a functionality](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Field-Types#common-field-parameters) to load a custom field if a condition matches, using its `show_on_cb` parameter.

I've a scenario:

```
Product Type: ( ) A   ( ) B   ( ) C  //radio buttons
Field for A:  [                   ]  //textbox
Field for B:  [                   ]  //textbox
Field for C:  [                   ]  //textbox
```

The process what CMB offers is a PHP way, check a PHP condition, whether of any current state (WordPress Cookie) or a db return.

As I need to activate 'em when on radio button selection, in this way, I can't achieve that, because I can't pass any rule to the `show_on_cb` parameter that can trigger on radio button selection, and if the function return `false`, the whole `<div>` doesn't even showed up (so I can't pass any jQuery to trigger 'em).

How can I solve these:

1. I need to show respective fields as per radio button selection.
2. I need to show respective field what the db returns as selected.

Though I know I can achieve that solely with jQuery. I can accept any way using both PHP and jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I made a function that only works on `edit` page - that means the `show_on_cb` (value: `'show_on_cb' => 'myproducts_product_typeA'`) will work only if the post is edited, because I used the `get_current_screen()` to dictate that.

```
function myproducts_product_typeA( $field ) {
    global $post;
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( $screen->action !== 'add' && $screen->post_type == 'my-products' ) {
        $product_type = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mp_product_type', TRUE );
        if( $product_type === 'A' ) return 1;
    } else {
        return 1; //to show on add-new page by default
    }
}
```

So the above function will check the db and return `true` or `false` according to fetched data from db, but it will return `true` only when the post is edited. In new post it won't check the database, and simply return `true` because I want all the fields to be active then.

Then I'm gonna use jQuery to show/hide my necessary fields as per the radio button selection.